# Redirect from directory on subdomain to root

Tags: redirect

Google has indexed subdomain.thedomain.com/directory

I want that to redirect to thedomain.com

What goes in the .htaccess file? I've found all other combos but this

Please help!

Thanks in advance, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You did not find the correct documentation. Read this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs

**Update:**

As a start, write this into `directory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* http://thedomain.com/ [R,L,NE]
```

The `.*` means *anything*, and because the rule comes from a `.htaccess` file, this effectively means *anything in this directory*.

In total, this means: redirect anything in that directory to the homepage, using the options in brackets (which will just work).

Comment: This doesn't tell me how to redirect to the root... at least i dont think- it's too difficult to understand, which is why i came here. can anyone help me out?

Comment: So you want to redirect `http://subdomain.thedomain.com/directory/*` to the homepage `http://thedomain.com/`, no matter what the `*` was? Then just leave out the `$1` from the examples in the documentation. Or, if you meant something else, provide more examples in your question.

Comment: Yes exactly. `http://subdomain.thedomain.com/directory/` to redirect to `http://thedomain.com`. it doesn't matter what the * is because there is only this one page on google to redirect. Which example do I use? I'm sorry im a complete newb to this, i am lost as to where to even start. can you type it out for me?

Comment: will this take me from the `subdomain.domain.com/directory` to the `domain.com`? `#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/docs/(.+)  http://new.example.com/docs/$1  [R,L]` or does it take me to `domain.com/docs`?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* http://thedomain.com/ [R,L,NE]` made the site not come up. I need this one and only page `http://info.westmountgrand.com/welcome` to redirect to `http://westmountgrand.com` hope that is clearer

Comment: will this conflict with wordpress? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: First, write some rubbish into the `.htaccess` file and try again. If you get an `Internal Server Error`, everything is fine. If you don't, the file is not even interpreted.

Comment: yes, it will. You need to put your rule before all other `RewriteRules`.

Comment: But you wrote your rule directly after the `RewriteBase` line? And that line is in the `.htaccess` file? And you get a server error when you write rubbish into that file?